# "To alarm someone about something" or "To alarm someone against something" to take a specific action

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I would like to express the importance of a surveillance system in preventing urban disasters. First I present some facts about a certain tragic event, then I claim that a surveillance mechanism could have helped us prevent such a disaster and save lives.

Here goes my sentence:

> An effective surveillance mechanism could have alarmed us take necessary actions and eventually save those people.

but what I really wanted to was to stress that ***this mechanism has the ability to sense the overcrowding.*** I would like to say that ***it could have alarmed us against overcrowding***. So the kind of sentence that I intend to build is closer to following in terms of content:

> An effective surveillance mechanism could have alarmed us against overcrowding, helped us take necessary actions and save those people.

But but I cannot find a way to formulate this sentence in a grammatically correct way.

I would appreaciate any help on constructing such a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't the structure of your sentence, but rather that you misunderstand the use of "alarm" as a verb:

> alarm (v):
>   1. Make (someone) feel frightened, disturbed, or in danger.
>   2. (be alarmed) Be fitted or protected with an alarm.

With the first definition, when you "alarm" someone you make them upset and fearful.  Example:

> Susan was **alarmed** by her friend's erratic driving, and begged her to pull over.

The second definition is almost exclusively used as the past participle, and in a very limited context that doesn't fit your sentence.

Instead David Siegel's suggestion of "alert" makes more sense.

> **[alert](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/alert)** (v): Warn (someone) of a danger or problem.

to put it another way: An alarm is designed to *alert* someone that something is wrong.  You can set up alarms that detect overcrowding, but the action of these alarms is to raise awareness:

> An effective urban surveillance system could have **alerted** authorities to potentially dangerous overcrowding, giving them time to take steps to prevent injury or death.

And precede or follow this with the description of such a system:

> The system includes a network of sensors that measure crowd density, along with various **alarms** triggered when density reaches dangerous levels.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "could have alarmed us take necessary actions' is not grammatical. one could write "could have alarmed us **to** take necessary actions", but much better would be "could have **alerted** us **to** take necessary actions". See [this google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alarmed+us+to%2C+alerted+us+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calarmed%20us%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calerted%20us%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Calarmed%20us%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calerted%20us%20to%3B%2Cc0)

Similarly while "could have alarmed us against overcrowding" is not incorrect, "could have **alerted** us against overcrowding" (no "to" is needed in this construction) is much more natural. See [this ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alarmed+against%2Calerted+against&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calarmed%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calerted%20against%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Calarmed%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calerted%20against%3B%2Cc0)